# How do I retrieve the first value from an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, youtube

I have a call to a YouTube XML sheet that works perfectly fine. However, I am having trouble setting a value from one of the arrays. I want the first value from "songID" to be set as "first". I've tried doing this:

```
var first = songID[0]
```

but it only makes a new array with only the first character of each value... Any suggestions?

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var pURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/F9183F81E7808428?v=2&alt=json&callback=?';
    $.getJSON(pURL, function(data) {
        $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
        var songID = item.media$group.media$content[0].url.substring(25, [36]);
        var songTitle = item.title.$t;
        var descript = item.media$group.media$description.$t;
        var songAth = descript.slice(3);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: can you upload the json text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already in an `each()` loop, so you shouldn't try to access it as an array, but just as a value. Just try:

```
if(i == 0){
  var first = songID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var pURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/9002A5F66694EBA0?v=2&alt=json&callback=?';
    $.getJSON(pURL, function(data) {
        $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
        var songID = item.media$group.media$content[0].url.substring(25, [36]);
        var songTitle = item.title.$t;
        var descript = item.media$group.media$description.$t;
        var songAth = descript.slice(3);
        if(i==0){
            alert("firstId is "+songID );
        }
        });           
    });
});
```

or just for first id:

```
var pURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/9002A5F66694EBA0?v=2&alt=json&callback=?';
    $.getJSON(pURL, function(data) {
        console.log(data.feed.entry[0].media$group.media$content[0].url.substring(25, [36]));  
        });         
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure what you're getting is actually an array? What makes you think that? Because if you ask for aString[0], you'll still get the first character back, because you can access string characters as if they're array elements. If it is indeed an array, just use var myString = myArray.join(""); and it'll become a string.